# New records are being created when existing records should be used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out why when I post data to my MVC4 controller, new records are created when existing records should be used.

My controller is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Song song) {
    JsonBase jsonBase;
    var dbSong = _songRepository.FindById(song.Id);
    TryUpdateModel(dbSong, String.Empty, null, new String[] { "CreatedDate", "SongAlternateTitles", "SongWriterSongs", "Exploitations" });
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        jsonBase = new JsonBase(true, null, new { Id = dbSong.Id });
    }
    else {
        jsonBase = new JsonBase(false, ModelState.Values);
    }
    return Json(jsonBase);
}
```

The Song object looks as follows:

```
public class Song : IEntity
{
    public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Song Title cannot exceed 128 characters")]
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(512, ErrorMessage = "Song Description cannot exceed 512 characters")]
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8000, ErrorMessage="Song lyrics cannot exceed 4096 characters")]
    public virtual String Lyrics { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Song Status")]
    public virtual Boolean isMaster { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "File Path cannot exceed 256 characters.")]
    public virtual String AudioFilePath { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "File Path cannot exceed 256 characters.")]
    public virtual String CoverImageFilePath { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Int32? BPM { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SongAlternateTitles> SongAlternateTitles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exploitation> Exploitations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SongWriterSong> SongWriterSongs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tweak> Tweaks { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing in JSON Data that looks as follows:

```
{"id":681,"title":"Another You","description":"Cascada - Everytime We Touch","lyrics":"","ismaster":false,"audiofilepath":"http://songistry.blob.core.windows.net/audiosamples/3211556309.mp3","coverimagefilepath":"http://songistry.blob.core.windows.net/coverimages/2711679216.jpg","tags":[{"id":43,"name":"Edgy","description":"This music is on the edge!","valid":true,"editing":false,"checked":true},{"id":44,"name":"Pop","description":"This music pops!","valid":true,"editing":false,"checked":true},{"id":47,"name":"Positive","description":"Positive","valid":true,"editing":false,"checked":true},{"id":45,"name":"Quirky","description":"Quirky","valid":true,"editing":false,"checked":true},{"id":46,"name":"R&B","description":"R&B","valid":true,"editing":false,"checked":true}],"songalternatetitles":[],"exploitations":[],"songwritersongs":[{"Id":742,"Pro":{"Id":2,"Name":"ASCAP"},"Publisher":{"Id":2,"Name":"Some Publisher","Phone":"4035555555","ContactName":"Some Guy","ContactEmail":"guy@songistry.com","ContactPhone":"4035555555","Address":"123 fake street"},"Percentage":100,"SongWriter":{"Id":1,"FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Cottingham","Name":"Mike Cottingham","Pro":{"Id":2,"Name":"ASCAP"},"Publisher":{"Id":2,"Name":"Some Publisher","Phone":"4035555555","ContactName":"Some Guy","ContactEmail":"guy@songistry.com","ContactPhone":"4035555555","Address":"123 fake street"}}},{"Id":771,"Pro":{"Id":206,"Name":"ACUM"},"Publisher":{"Id":2,"Name":"Some Publisher","Phone":"4035555555","ContactName":"Some Guy","ContactEmail":"guy@songistry.com","ContactPhone":"4035555555","Address":"123 fake street"},"Percentage":0,"SongWriter":{"Id":8,"FirstName":"Jessica","LastName":"Cottingham","Name":"Jessica Cottingham","Pro":{"Id":1,"Name":"Socan"},"Publisher":{"Id":2,"Name":"Some Publisher","Phone":"4035555555","ContactName":"Some Guy","ContactEmail":"guy@songistry.com","ContactPhone":"4035555555","Address":"123 fake street"}}}]}
```

New records are being created for tags when existing records should be used.  What am I doing wrong?  I assumed that if I passed tags in that contained ID's that the model binder would figure that out automatically.

Comment: Model binding to entities is a strong anti-pattern for security and architectural reasons. Maybe you should get rid of that.

Comment: public virtual String Title { get; set; }...why string is String..i mean with capital lettar?

Comment: @usr Thank you for your comment, however, without a little elaboration it offers zero value..

Comment: @BhushanFirake preference only.  In c# string is an alias for System.String, I just prefer to use String, but they are technically the same thing.

Comment: @mcottingham It is recommended for objects to use string and String for classes...

Comment: @BhushanFirake I understand the standard conventions, that said, I prefer to use String.  Regardless, this has no bearing on why I'm having this issue.

Comment: Let me elaborate then :) When binding to a `User` object any HTTP client can set its `IsAdmin` property to true if you intended this or not! I found that MVC works best if you always use a custom model class. It is created very quickly and offers complete control over what you receive and how you process it. Anyway, this is just a sidenote, not an answer.

Comment: @usr fair enough, thanks!  I guess I should probably create a viewmodel for this instance then.  I use them everywhere else.

Comment: In the interest of keeping this thread useful I will post a detailed answer on how I solved this problem.  As some people here probably know, simply creating a view model does not resolve this issue.  The issue is that the existing "tag" entities need to be pulled into the existing context, or attached to existing entities without changing their state in the database.

Comment: Sorry for off topic, but Bhushan Firake,  when coding back and forth in Java and C#,  using String is by far easier since it works in both environments.

Comment: Is the question resolved for you? Did my answer help? Please comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model binder doesn't know anything about IDs. It doesn't know what an ID even is. So it cannot *merge* the changes from the JSON to the Tags collection.

I'm not sure there is a solution with the way you directly bind to entities. I recommend creating view models for the whole structure (which isn't so much work as the view model classes are trivial DTOs). Then, you need to manually merge the changes which probably involves doing a join between the view-model tags and the entity tags.

This is a good system, even if it seems laborious at first. It gives yo total control. You can even add processes such as "if and only if a tag name changed, I will set the TagNameChangeDateTime to UtcNow". Binding cannot be extended to do such things.

Comment: This is how I ended up solving this issue.  Thanks for your help!